# Need best combination of array elements for specific sum with minimum wastage

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

I've to code a Program in which user input values for array and program calculate the number of 14,16 and 18's sum and element combination for that particular sum with minimum wastage.

Like {3,6,12,7,1,4}

here

```
 14's sum=0 with wastage:0   And combination:0
 16's sum=1 with wastage:0   And combination:12,4
 18's sum=1 with wastage:1   And combination:3,6,7,1
 Total Wastage:1
```

And Other can be

```
 14's sum=0 with wastage:0   And combination:0
 16's sum=1 with wastage:1   And combination:3,7,1,4
 18's sum=1 with wastage:0   And combination:12,6
 Total Wastage:1
```

I thinks It's best.

And can be Other Combination with greater wastage.

Now the problem is I have to calculate permutations(through recursion) for input array and then apply logic which calculate sequentially for any permutation...and choose the best with lowest Total wastage from all permutation.My Code is OK for values of 1 to 7. onward like 8,9 or more, calculation time increases with a big difference because of increasing permutation numbers and their objects.I want the code to work for around 50 numbers.

Can any one suggest any better solution or change?

My code:

Class for deal with one permutation.

```
public class ResultSet {

public int fourteen = 0, sixteen = 0, eighteen = 0;

int ElementSum = 0, TotalWastage = 0, LastActivated = 0;
int[] FourteenWastages, SixteenWastages, EighteenWastages, InputCombination;
String[] FourteenCombination;
String[] SixteenCombination;
String[] EighteenCombination;

public ResultSet(int[] in) {
    InputCombination = in;
    FourteenWastages = new int[InputCombination.length];
    SixteenWastages = new int[InputCombination.length];
    EighteenWastages = new int[InputCombination.length];
    FourteenCombination = new String[InputCombination.length];
    SixteenCombination = new String[InputCombination.length];
    EighteenCombination = new String[InputCombination.length];
    selector();
    wastagecalculator();
}

public void details() {
    System.out.println("Fourteen: " + fourteen);
    for (int j = 0; j < fourteen; j++) {
        System.out.println("With wastegs:" + FourteenWastages[j] + "\tAnd Combination=" + FourteenCombination[j]);
    }
    System.out.println("---------------------");
    System.out.println("Sixteen: " + sixteen);
    for (int j = 0; j < sixteen; j++) {
        System.out.println("With wastegs:" + SixteenWastages[j] + "\tAnd Combination=" + SixteenCombination[j]);
    }
    System.out.println("---------------------");
    System.out.println("Eighteen: " + eighteen);
    for (int j = 0; j < eighteen; j++) {
        System.out.println("With wastegs:" + EighteenWastages[j] + "\tAnd Combination=" + EighteenCombination[j]);
    }
    System.out.println("---------------------");
    System.out.println("Total Wastage=" + TotalWastage);
    System.out.println("********************************");
}

final void selector() {
    for (int j = 0; j < InputCombination.length; j++) {

        ElementSum += InputCombination[j];
        if (FourteenCombination[j] == null) {
            FourteenCombination[j] = "";
        }
        if (SixteenCombination[j] == null) {
            SixteenCombination[j] = "";
        }
        if (EighteenCombination[j] == null) {
            EighteenCombination[j] = "";
        }
        FourteenCombination[fourteen] += InputCombination[j];
        SixteenCombination[sixteen] += InputCombination[j];
        EighteenCombination[eighteen] += InputCombination[j];

        if (ElementSum <= 14) {
            if (LastActivated != 1) {
                if (LastActivated == 2) {
                    if (ElementSum + (16 - SixteenWastages[sixteen - 1]) <= 16) {
                        SixteenWastages[sixteen - 1] = 16 - (16 - SixteenWastages[sixteen - 1] + ElementSum);
                        SixteenCombination[sixteen - 1] += ElementSum;
                        FourteenCombination[fourteen] = SixteenCombination[sixteen] = EighteenCombination[eighteen] = "";
                        ElementSum = 0;
                        LastActivated = 2;
                    } else if (ElementSum + (16 - SixteenWastages[sixteen - 1]) <= 18) {
                        sixteen--;
                        eighteen++;
                        EighteenWastages[eighteen - 1] = 18 - (16 - SixteenWastages[sixteen] + ElementSum);
                        EighteenCombination[eighteen - 1] = SixteenCombination[sixteen] + ElementSum;
                        FourteenCombination[fourteen] = SixteenCombination[sixteen] = SixteenCombination[sixteen + 1] = "";
                        SixteenWastages[sixteen] = ElementSum = 0;
                        LastActivated = 3;
                    } else {
                        fourteen++;
                        FourteenWastages[fourteen - 1] = 14 - ElementSum;
                        ElementSum = 0;
                        SixteenCombination[sixteen] = EighteenCombination[eighteen] = "";
                        LastActivated = 1;
                    }
                } else if (LastActivated == 3 && (ElementSum + (18 - EighteenWastages[eighteen - 1]) <= 18)) {
                    EighteenWastages[eighteen - 1] = 18 - (18 - EighteenWastages[eighteen - 1] + ElementSum);
                    EighteenCombination[eighteen - 1] += ElementSum;
                    FourteenCombination[fourteen] = SixteenCombination[sixteen] = EighteenCombination[eighteen] = "";
                    ElementSum = 0;
                    LastActivated = 3;
                } else {
                    fourteen++;
                    FourteenWastages[fourteen - 1] = 14 - ElementSum;
                    ElementSum = 0;
                    SixteenCombination[sixteen] = EighteenCombination[eighteen] = "";
                    LastActivated = 1;
                }

            } else if (LastActivated == 1) {
                if ((14 - FourteenWastages[fourteen - 1] + ElementSum) <= 14) {
                    FourteenWastages[fourteen - 1] = 14 - ((14 - FourteenWastages[fourteen - 1] + ElementSum));
                    ElementSum = 0;
                    FourteenCombination[fourteen - 1] += FourteenCombination[fourteen];
                    SixteenCombination[sixteen] = EighteenCombination[eighteen] = FourteenCombination[fourteen] = "";
                    LastActivated = 1;
                } else if ((14 - FourteenWastages[fourteen - 1] + ElementSum) <= 16) {
                    fourteen--;
                    sixteen++;
                    SixteenWastages[sixteen - 1] = 16 - (14 - FourteenWastages[fourteen] + ElementSum);
                    FourteenWastages[fourteen] = 0;
                    SixteenCombination[sixteen - 1] = FourteenCombination[fourteen] + ElementSum;
                    FourteenCombination[fourteen] = EighteenCombination[eighteen] = "";
                    LastActivated = 2;
                    ElementSum = 0;
                } else if ((14 - FourteenWastages[fourteen - 1] + ElementSum) <= 18) {
                    fourteen--;
                    eighteen++;
                    EighteenWastages[eighteen - 1] = 18 - (14 - FourteenWastages[fourteen] + ElementSum);
                    FourteenWastages[fourteen] = 0;
                    EighteenCombination[eighteen - 1] = FourteenCombination[fourteen] + ElementSum;
                    FourteenCombination[fourteen] = SixteenCombination[sixteen] = "";
                    LastActivated = 3;
                    ElementSum = 0;
                } else {
                    fourteen++;
                    FourteenWastages[fourteen - 1] = 14 - ElementSum;
                    SixteenCombination[sixteen] = EighteenCombination[eighteen] = "";
                    LastActivated = 1;
                    ElementSum = 0;
                }
            }
        } else if (ElementSum > 14 && ElementSum <= 16) {
            sixteen++;
            SixteenWastages[sixteen - 1] = 16 - ElementSum;
            ElementSum = 0;
            FourteenCombination[sixteen] = EighteenCombination[eighteen] = "";
            LastActivated = 2;
        } else if (ElementSum > 16 && ElementSum <= 18) {
            eighteen++;
            EighteenWastages[eighteen - 1] = 18 - ElementSum;
            ElementSum = 0;
            FourteenCombination[fourteen] = SixteenCombination[sixteen] = "";
            LastActivated = 3;
        }

    }
}

final void wastagecalculator() {
    for (int i = 0; i < fourteen; i++) {
        TotalWastage += FourteenWastages[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < sixteen; i++) {
        TotalWastage += SixteenWastages[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < eighteen; i++) {
        TotalWastage += EighteenWastages[i];
    }
}
}
```

Main Class:

```
public class Alumcalc {
public static int[][] InputCombinationsArray;
public static int[] InputArray ={11, 2, 16, 3, 15, 10}; 
public static ResultSet[] CombinationsArray, SortedCombinationsArray;
public static int Factorial;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Factorial = factorial(InputArray.length);
    InputCombinationsArray = new int[Factorial][InputArray.length];
    CombinationsArray = new ResultSet[Factorial];
    Permute(InputArray, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < Factorial; i++) {
        CombinationsArray[i] = new ResultSet(InputCombinationsArray[i]);
    }
    SortedCombinationsArray = CombinationsArray;
    sort();   //From Other Class
    topfive();  //From Other Class
}
}
```

Now

```
Permute(InputArray, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < Factorial; i++) {
        CombinationsArray[i] = new ResultSet(InputCombinationsArray[i]);
    }
```

are taking Time..and for 10 or > recursion of permutation fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are solving the classical *knapsack* problem, one of the famous NP problems. By definition, NP problems are intractable for any larger N (50 definitely qualifies as large here).

There is no simple advice on how to improve your code: you'll have to look into various options for *heuristic* algorithms, which do not guarantee finding the true optimum. Different algorithms have different goods and bads about them and the art is to find one which best matches the specific details of your problem.